# How to extract images from a file using Apache TIka?

Tags: apache-tika

I have a pdf (or any other type of files such as .doc, .ppt, etc) which contain text as well as images. How can I extract images from those files using Tika?

Can also run OCR on the extracted images using Tess4j or any other lib?

This is how I call Tika:

```
 AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
 BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(writeLimit);
 Metadata metadata = new Metadata();        
 InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("file.pdf");      
 parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
```

p.s. I have tika-app.jar.

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? The way to enable recursion and/or saving of embedded resources differs depending on how you call it (java, facade, tika-app, tika-server etc)

Comment: @Gagravarr:  I edited my original post to show how I call Tika.

Comment: Does the [Extract Embedded Files example from the Apache Tika examples module](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ExtractEmbeddedFiles.java) not do you then?

Comment: I was not aware of thi. May I knw what exactly it does? does it do OCR?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Just to clarify, the image files are part of the document, not attachment, Can I still extract them using this piece of code?

Comment: It doesn't OCR, that's up to you. Once you're given an embedded or attached document, you can save it, give it to an OCR program, give it back to Tika, whatever takes your fancy!

Comment: @Gagravarr: I looked at the example you sent me but can't quite figure out how it extract the embedded files. Let's say a pdf document has 2 scanned picture and one text page. How it treats it?

Comment: The same way that the `-z` flag of the Tika App does. Just try it and see!

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this:

```
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
        PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
        ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();

        parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, config);
        parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
        parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser); // need to add this to make
                                                // sure recursive parsing
                                                // happens!
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, parseContext);
        String text = handler.toString().trim();
```

---

1) Ensure that you have tesseract installed using 'tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.00dev.exe' from:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/
and have its path (It will get installed in the program files, if windows) is placed in the PATH environment variable. Restart Windows if needed. 
Pass any (yes any!) file and it will extract.
2) Download tess4j-3.0.0.jar from:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/?source=typ_redirect
and refer this jar using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

then, these:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, if using Ubuntu, tesseract should be installed using apt-get.
It will work.

Comment: Is this specific for PDF or does it extract images from other formats supported by Tika, like MS Word or Pages files?

Comment: @jmng "Pass any (yes any!) file and it will extract."